# How to carry over a workflow variable to another workflow? SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow variable that collects email addresses called from a dozen of if-else statements. However, I have created another workflow that needs to reference that aforementioned workflow variable. ( They are from 2 different lists ). Is there a way to do this? Especially because the variable has a number of strings in it - the email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a column that houses the variable. Make it a single line of text, and then you can pick it up in the next workflow by referencing the ID of the list item. Depending on how the two lists are related, you could also create a list that is the joining list to create the variable.

Comment: Thanks Mike that worked like a charm! I wish you were around more. :)

Comment: glad to have helped! :)